# Replacing number values in a pandas data frame column with strings values from another data frame column indexed by those 5 digit numbers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, types

I have two data frames, A and B.

df'**A**':

| Col 1 |
| --- |
| 57253,00987(4567) |
| asdf(78985>00987) |

column A is string type.

df'**B**':

| Col 1 | Col 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 57253 | TRUE |
| 78985 | NEGATIVE |
| 00987 | LAUGHS |

Some of the numbers in Col 1 of df'**A**' is present in Col 1 of df'**B**'

I want to replace the number values in df'**A**' with the string values in Col 2 from df'**B**' that share the index with the same number in Col 1 of df'**B**'.

So the expected result(updated df'**A**') would be:

| Col 1 |
| --- |
| TRUE,LAUGHS(4567) |
| asdf(NEGATIVE>LAUGHS) |

Using "for i in dfA.index:" I have tried:

Initially, the .replace(), .update() methods but don't think I can achieve the result with those.

I have tried using regex (the numbers that need replacing are always 5 digits) operations for over half a day but I'm not getting desired result (I new to this). But I'm glad I'm learning regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope, this works for your solution.
I create an custom function for every value of df_A and check it's value with the second dataframe values.

```
import pandas as pd
df_A = pd.DataFrame([
    {'Col 1': '57253,00987(4567)'},
    {'Col 1': 'asdf(78985>00987)'}
])
df_B = pd.DataFrame([
    {'Col 1': '57253', 'Col 2': 'TRUE'},
    {'Col 1': '78985', 'Col 2': 'NEGATIVE'},
    {'Col 1': '00987', 'Col 2': 'LAUGHS'},
])
def updateVal(v):
    for col_1, col_2 in df_B.values:
        if col_1 in v:
            v = v.replace(col_1, col_2)
    return v
    
df_A['Col 1'] = df_A['Col 1'].apply(updateVal)
df_A
```